# ¿Cómo evitar que las cadenas con acentos se guarden con signo raros o signo de interrogación de cierre(?) en mi tabla?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

He tratado usando este código en mi función para remover acentos.

```
create or replace FUNCTION   REMOVE_ACCENTS (P_TEXT  IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS

   l_text VARCHAR2(32767) := null;

begin
   l_text := TRANSLATE(P_TEXT,'áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ','aeiouAEIOU');

   return (l_text);

end REMOVE_ACCENTS;
```

Pero no funciona esta uniendo columnas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El NLS_CHARACTERSET : WE8ISO8859P15

Se carga un archivo plano con codificación ANSI pero al cargar el archivo los acentos los guarda con signo de interrogación de cierre (?) lo que genera que se una una columna tras otra y deformando la información.

```
Declare
   l_query            Varchar2(32767) := Null;
   

Begin
     Begin
        Delete From Broadcast;
        commit;
       Delete From Ax_Gl_Interface
       Where category = 'REVENUES';
        Commit;
    End;
  

    apex_collection.create_or_truncate_collection('REVENUES');
    
    apex_collection.delete_collection(p_collection_name => 'REVENUES');         


    l_query := 'select Limpiar_Texto_Ach(upper(p.col001)),
                       REMOVE_ACCENTS(p.col002),          
                       Limpiar_Texto_Ach(p.col003)
                from apex_application_temp_files f, 
                table( apex_data_parser.parse(
                                      p_content                     => f.blob_content,
                                      p_skip_rows                   => 1,
                                      p_store_profile_to_collection => ''FILE_PARSER_COLLECTION'',
                                      p_file_name                   => f.filename ) ) p
     where 1=1
       and f.name = '''||:P2_FILE||'''';
     
     
    APEX_COLLECTION.CREATE_COLLECTION_FROM_QUERY (
        p_collection_name => 'REVENUES', 
        p_query => l_query,
        p_generate_md5 => 'NO');

    
     commit;
     
     
     END;
```

Comment: No es necesario hacer eso, sólo tienes que usar la codificación correcta. ¿Cuál cliente usas?. Etiqueta el motor de base de datos.

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: Si "no funciona" diría que probablemente cuándo llamas la función ya no van _acentos_ allí, lo que apunta a la lectura del archivo. De nuevo, sin ver el código, sin una muestra del archivo (virgen) o saber más detalles, cómo saberlo...

Comment: Lo añadire es una colección

Comment: `parse` espera que los archivos estén en UTF8. Si no está en esa codificación el archivo, como sospechaba, el error está en la lectura. Pasa el valor apropiado usando el parámetro `P_FILE_CHARSET`. Habría que ver la codificación que trae el archivo, por ejemplo `WE8MSWIN1252` podría hacer la tarea.

Comment: Documentación: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aeapi/PARSE-Function.html

Comment: Trae codificación ANSI

Comment: Ya se solvento, gracias

Comment: @jachguate Por favor https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/601138/como-incluir-valores-nulos-en-un-rango-de-datos-en-pl-sql vea mi pregunta.