# ¿Como incluir valores nulos en un rango de datos en PL/SQL?

Tags: plsql

tengo la siguiente consulta :

```
SELECT period_name Periodo, 
       period_year year,
       credito,
       debito
 FROM Journal
WHERE 1=1 
AND ledger_id = 1
AND actual_flag = 'A'
AND period_year BETWEEN 'AUG-22' AND 'SEP-22'
AND fondo BETWEEN NVL('0000', fondo)  AND  NVL('8000', fondo)
AND code BETWEEN NVL('000', ano)  AND NVL('012', ano)
```

**Pero la salida excluye los valores nulos de la columna code por lo que el between del code no es funcional**

También probé con este otro filtro

```
Select period_name Periodo, 
       period_year year 
 From Journal
WHERE 1=1 
AND ledger_id = 1
AND actual_flag = 'A'
AND period_year BETWEEN 'AUG-22' AND 'SEP-22'
AND fondo between  NVL('0000', fondo)  AND  NVL('8000', fondo)
AND code >= '000' --Desde
AND (code is null or code <= '012') --Hasta
```

¿Existirá otra forma de incluir esos valores nulos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claro que si.

Antes, repasemos por qué no está funcionando lo que has intentado.

1. En la primera consulta, creo que no has comprendido bien como funciona [`NVL()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/NVL.html). Esta función, que pre-data a [`coalesce()`] va a devolver el primer parámetro que recibe si es NO nulo, y si el primero es nulo, devuelve el segundo. Así, `NVL('0000', fondo) siempre va a devolver` '0000'`, pues no hay posibilidad que este sea nulo.

   Por esto mismo,

   ```
   code BETWEEN NVL('000', ano)  AND NVL('012', ano)
   ```

   Es exactamente igual a:

   ```
   code BETWEEN '000' AND '012'
   ```

   Y esto excluye a todos los valores nulos, pues ninguno va a dar positivo a la condición `between`.

   Por otro lado, en tiempos modernos, yo recomiendo el uso de `coalesce()` y no de `NVL()`, pues hace lo mismo pero puede recibir N parámetros y devuelve el primero que sea no nulo, y null en caso que todos lo sean.
2. En la segunda consulta, un valor nulo va a dar `true` a la condición:

   ```
   (code is null or code <= '012')
   ```

   Pero ese mismo valor nulo va a dar `false` a la condición anterior:

   ```
   code >= '000'
   ```

   Entonces, para cualquier valor nulo estas condiciones se reducen a:

   ```
   ... and false and true
   ```

   Y sabemos que esto devuelve false. Como todos los valores nulos van a dar falso a esa condición, el resultado los va a excluir a todos.

Debes construir una condición que incluya a los nulos Y además a los que estén dentro del rango de valores.

Para lograrlo, usa el operador OR.

Por ejemplo:

```
select   period_name Periodo
       , period_year year
       , credito
       , debito
  from Journal
 where ledger_id = 1
   and actual_flag = 'A'
   and period_year between 'AUG-22' and 'SEP-22'
   and fondo between '0000' and '8000'
   and (   code is null
        or code between '000' and '012'
       )
```